# HTTPS to HTTP debug proxy?

Tags: proxy, ssl, https

I searched the whole google but only thing I have found is for your own server - like for example for [appache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)  but I want to have a proxy in my hands - which will simply act as a man in the middle and intercepts the connection.

The whole idea is that I have 2 applications which I have upgraded to SSL but right now I can't debug them for the same reason.

I know about fiddler but that doesn't output http - it only intercepts.

Comment: I don't understand your demands. Fiddler will display the HTML for HTTP(S), so what else do you need for debug?

Comment: HTTP output so I can attach a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mitmproxy. That said, you will need the ssl-certificate obviously, because ssl is encrypted. Would it be easier to do this, there would be no point in HTTPS whatsoever.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I can't give examples because I don't know your system, but here's the documentation of mitmproxy: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/  


Your SSL Certificate is generated by you, so you should be able to supply it. If you can't, I would recommend to just switch back to HTTP, which is way easier to debug.

Comment: Despite my name I'm running on linux.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you are trieing to say with your comment. mitmproxy is a program for linux.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87231/https-to-http-proxy-using-mitmproxy-org